# $lim_{n→∞}P((/1√n)\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(−1)^{i}X_{i}\leq$x) equals?

Tags: normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, characteristic-function

Let X1, X2, . . . be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with variance 2.
Then for all x,
$lim_{n→∞}P((/1√n)\sum\limits_{i=1}^n(−1)^{i}X_{i}\leq$x)
equals

$(A) Φ(x√2)$

$(B) Φ(x/√2)$

$(C) Φ(x)$

$(D) Φ(2x)$

I tried using central limit theorem by following the limits but there was no result
Which method should I try to solve it?

Comment: Use the CLT.  To do so, you need to compute the mean and variance of each term to find their limiting values.

Comment: Since the terms in the sun are not iid due to that (-1)^i, perhaps you need something a bit stronger than the ordinary CLT, like the Lyapunov CLT https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Lyapunov_CLT

Comment: How do I use it in this question. I have never used this extension

Comment: @Pedro No extension is necessary: simply break the sum into the sum over the odd terms (everything is now *iid*) and the sum over the even terms (*ditto*).